# How do I stop breaking strings so fast?

Tags: guitar, strings

I have a Squire Fender Telecaster. I play punk rock and usually keep the guitar in E♭ tuning. I broke a string on my Peavey Raptor recently, but it lasted longer.

D'Adarrio 10's and Slinky Cobalt 10's (I think they are 10's) are problematic for me. Should I go up in gauge?

Comment: which string was it that broke?

Comment: Hi- what do you call "fast" ? how long did the strings last ?

Answer (score 4):

Currently you have far too many variables for a specific answer here, however these are the things to think about:

- How often do you change strings? Some change theirs every week, others once a year or longer. It's worth thinking about how often you want to do it. I am happy changing my strings once every six months, but occasionally I need to change my top E more often, depending on how many gigs I play, and how hot they are (sweat has a bad effect on strings)
- Do you like the sound of the 10's? 11's will sound different. 9's are probably too thin for punk or any heavy/energetic guitar, but 10's are pretty robust, especially when downtuned a semitone.
- Where did the string break? In the middle, and it's just worn, but at an end implies a possible sharp edge at bridge or nut.
- Have you tried a string cleaning product, or at least a wipe down after each gig - this will extend the life of your strings.

We do have a few questions here on breaking strings, so well worth a look around the [guitar](/questions/tagged/guitar) tag.